# Transfer a google sheet with form and apps script to someone else

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been asked to make a google form that tracks responses in a google sheet as well as emails the answers to the gmail account for which the sheet and form belong. The form will be somewhat complex with several branching options. There will be a small Google Apps Script function to generate and format the email based on which branches were followed. There will be another sheet in the gsheets file that does some calculations and formulas to provide various displays of the answer data. Additionally, they would like me to generate a QR code to the URL of the fillable form.

I do not have any questions about developing this - I have several very similar complex forms and sheets with apps script on my own account. But, I've never developed something like this for someone else. I want to make this on my own google account so that I can test things before giving it to the person who wants it.

**My questions is this:** What hurdles can I expect to face when attempting to give this project to the other person? The other person is very computer illiterate and would like to not be involved in anything more complex than "click this link to accept ownership". Is this as simple as me making a Sheets file (with a form addon and GAS script extension) and then "transfer ownership" and then removing myself? We are both using simple "personal google accounts", and not Google Workspace accounts. If it is not that simple, I need to prepare something that will help the other person accept ownership and have the form/sheet begin functioning properly for her.

Some hurdles that I believe I might face: I'm concerned about the form becoming de-linked from the sheet, or possibly the URL to the form changing when the form/sheet combo changes "ownership", which would invalidate the QR code. I'm also concerned that the apps script will not "transfer" without some sort of re-authorization.

I haven't yet tried developing the sheet/form combo. I don't want to get too far into the weeds if this is not going to be as "simple" and making it and then giving it.  I may have to decline the project, based on the other person wanting it as simple as possible on their end.

Comment: If you put the form and spreadsheet on a shared drive and you both have full permission then when they remove it, it's now theirs.  Now they will have to authorize the script and for that you may wish to get their login if they trust you and let you do it.  I do this for my daughter occasionally because having to make it a cloud platform project can be a bit daunting for a person that knows nothing about scripts.  Hell it's still a bit daunting for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using personal accounts the best approach would be to share ownership of the Google sheet bound with the Script, this is noted in this [Collaborate with other developers documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/collaborating#collaboration_basics). As Google Sheet is managed as a regular Drive file you will be able to share the file to the person that will become the owner and once accepted you should then transfer ownership of the file. Another option would as well be that once completed the script the other person can make a [copy of the Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#access_to_bound_scripts) that has the bound script so it automatically creates a file with the script included.